# How can I add a specific CSS rule in Chrome that would apply for any site I'm visiting

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

So the problem that I have it's simple z-index overlap between 2 chrome extensions that I'm using.

Is there anyway to add my own custom CSS rule that would be applied on a browser level without creating another Chrome extension?

Comment: It's not very clear if the 2 extensions you use were created by you or if you're just a mere user.
I don't know if I will be able to help you but to make your problem clearer you could upload an image that represents your problem.
I know that there are ready-made extensions that allow you to set and save your style preferences on the web pages you visit, some of these I have also used in the past.
However, I can't confirm that these do their duty in the presence of content scripts injected by other extensions.
If the extensions inject custom elements with closed shadowDom I see it hard...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ok, here is some more context :)

There are 2 chrome extensions:
- Google Translator
- Bionic Reading

Google translator provides a popup for any selected text on the page.
Bionic Reading creates a special layout that improves reading speed for any site.

But Bionic Reading creates layout with z-index that is higher than z-index for popup that generates by Google Translator.

All I need is to add proper z-index for this selector: ".jfk-bubble.gtx-bubble" and I need to save this css rule as the default for my browser. How should I do it?